# (MySQL) SQL Error : ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column '<Column Name>' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, sql

Not sure what i am doing wrong here:

```
mysql> use co_sysdev;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
mysql> select * from system_params;
Empty set (0.01 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO system_params (NUM_ENGINE_D_PROCESSES,MAX_NUM_BATCHES_PER_CLIENT,MAX_NUM_BATCHES_PER_LOCATION) VALUES(5,8,2);
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'NUM_ENGINE_D_PROCESSES' in 'field list'
mysql>
```

also:

```
 desc system_params;
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field     | Type                                                                                               | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| attribute | enum('NUM_ENGINE_D_PROCESSES','MAX_NUM_BATCHES_PER_CLIENT','MAX_NUM_BATCHES_PER_LOCATION') | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| value     | varchar(256)                                                                                       | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

also:

```
 show create table system_params;
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table         | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| system_params | CREATE TABLE `system_params` (
  `attribute` enum('NUM_ENGINE_D_PROCESSES','MAX_NUM_BATCHES_PER_CLIENT','MAX_NUM_BATCHES_PER_LOCATION') NOT NULL,
  `value` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`attribute`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+---------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: What does `show create table system_params` give you.

Comment: dude, `NUM_ENGINE_D_PROCESSES` is the enum value, not the column

Comment: since i am new to SQL not sure if -1 is fair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't use enum values as field names. Your insert has to be something like

```
INSERT INTO system_params (attribute, value) VALUES ('NUM_ENGINE_D_PROCESSES', 'foo');
```

unless your possible values that can be inserted here are unbounded (e.g. end-user definable), you're going down a very very painful path.

Answer (score 1):

well clearly this error says you are using wrong column name somwhere and `NUM_ENGINE_D_PROCESSES` is the enum value, and you are using it as column...
 the syntax of SQL insert query should be like

```
INSERT INTO your_table_Name (ID, name, ...<column names goes here>...) 
VALUES ('1', 'John', ...<values goes here>...);
```

in your case

```
INSERT INTO system_params (attribute, value) VALUES ('NUM_ENGINE_BLA_BLA', 'foo');
```